# How to call implemented step from one step definition into some other step definition using Java in Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am trying to call below step definition implementation

```
@Given("^a user is logged into application with \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")

public void a_user_is_logged_into_application_with_and(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable 
{
        open();
        login(arg1, arg2);

    }
```

from another step definition implementation like below:

```
@Given("^Run Add Business scenario$")
    public void run_Add_Business_scenario() {

         Given("a user is logged into application with 'clfmanager' and 'rules'");

    }
```

and i am not able to do it, Is there anyway i can do this?

Comment: you can not do that in cucumber, what you can do is create another step which calls these two functions are are interested in.

Comment: For using cucumber in ruby, it is easy to do so. I am now familiar with cucumber java but I found something like https://github.com/cucumber/cuke4duke/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-StepDefinitions. Hope this could help.

Comment: It would be nice to see details why you are not able to what you want to do. Did you get an error? Sharing details of what has happened is good for better answers.

Answer (score 3):

@canpan14 suggests this solution:

```
@Given("Login with username (.+) and password (.+)")
public void login(String user, String pass){
   // Login here
}

@Given("Login with defaults")
public void loginWithDefaults(){
   login("defaultUser","defaultPass")
}
```

Unfortunately, this is an example of calling a step from another step.

The solution I'm advocating would look more like this:

```
public class LoginSteps {

    private LoginHelper loginHelper = new LoginHelper();

    @Given("Login with username (.*) and password (.*)")
    public void login(String user, String pass) {
       loginHelper.login(user, pass)
    }

    @Given("Login with defaults")
    public void loginWithDefaults() {
       loginHelper.login("defaultUser", "defaultPass")
    }
}
```

A helper class with reusable logic:

```
public class LoginHelper {
    public void login(user, pass) {
        // login logic lives here and can be referenced from multiple steps
    }
}
```

The biggest difference is that I extracted the login logic to a method in a helper class. This allows me to write single line steps that are easy to understand.

I moved the helper method to another class to make sure that it is easy to get hold of no matter which step class you are calling it from.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is not to do this.

What you should do is to create a helper class that both steps use. This is the way to reuse, and avoid duplication, in Cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Thomas' provided an actual correct answer. I tried to replicated what the question was trying to do instead of fix the actual problem at hand. Thanks again Thomas!

Thomas is correct. To expand on it you could do something similar to the below:

```
@Given("Login with username (.+) and password (.+)")
public void login(String user, String pass){
   // Login here
}

@Given("Login with defaults")
public void loginWithDefaults(){
   login("defaultUser","defaultPass")
}
```

Remember even though we are using Given/When/Then, these are still just methods and can be used as methods.

Comment: I am afraid that this example is an example of calling a step from another step. This is exactly what you shouldn't do. I'll expand in an answer why.